# SOQL to fetch lead notes not working

Tags: soql, notes

I am trying to fetch all notes with respect to a lead record as following,

```
SELECT id,name,(SELECT Body,CreatedById,CreatedDate,Id,IsDeleted,IsPrivate,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,OwnerId,Owner.name,ParentId,SystemModstamp,Title FROM Notes) FROM Lead where id = '00QM000000Dubvq'
```

I am not getting a single record. Please help!

Comment: note records are created on `00QM000000Dubvq`?

Comment: Yes they are created

Comment: can you pls run this code in devloper console Query editor and check.

Comment: Thats what i did. Didnt get any records for notes. Its blank

Comment: is note record  accessible for current user means via UI?

Comment: I can see Notes related list on standard detail page where i can add as well as see all notes records.

Comment: If you able to access via UI, then you should able to access in apex. Hey join this chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32205/room-for-ratan-and-snehakem May be we can try to solve your issue.

Comment: IF you are getting more than 1 record then the cause is that you are using to filter the id of 15 carachters. Have you tryed to filter by id 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with @snehakem

There is Note related list on Lead object i.e. ContentDocument(child ContentDocumentLink )

We can query ContentDocumentLink based on lead id.

```
[SELECT Id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Description
             FROM ContentDocumentLink 
             WHERE LinkedEntityId='00Q9000000PjzOm'];
```

Then we can get the contentDocument Description.